# Comparison query without date object in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have day, month and year fields in my collection structure like below.

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("52e979810c27656f5f31ff9f"),
"day" : 9,
"mid" : 1,
"month" : 4,
"year" : 2017}
```

I'd like to get documents greater than a date. It is easy to compare documents by Date object but here there isn't a date field.

I tried to use $dateFromParts operator but because my MongoDB version is 3.4.19, it didn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator for that.

Just define the conditions and that's it.

Example:

```
var year = 2017, month = 4, day = 9;
db.getCollection('collection_name').find({
    $or: [
        {"year": {$gt: year}},
        {"year": {$eq: year}, "month": {$gt: month}},
        {"year": {$eq: year}, "month": {$eq: month}, "day": {$gt: day}}
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo code:

```
- start by checking if the year is bigger
- if the year is equal, then check if the month is bigger
- if the month is also equal, then check if the day is bigger
```

If all is false, then the date is not bigger